# Python (pygame) using the sprites and classes to make clones of images

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite, clone

```
import pygame
import time
import random #Loads pygame and clock and random function

pygame.init() #Intiates pygame

display_width = 1440
display_height = 900

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height)) 
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #Starts auto clock updater
AstImg = pygame.image.load('Images\Ast.gif') #Asteroid image

def asteroid(x,y): #Function for asteroid display
     gameDisplay.blit(AstImg,(x,y))

def game():
     background_image = pygame.image.load("Images/Space.jpg").convert() 
     e = 1
     x = 2500
     y = 2500
     ax = 2500
     ay = 2500
     bx = 2500
     by = 2500
     cx = 2500
     cy = 2500
     dx = 2500
     dy = 2500

    while e == 1:
        gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0, 0]) 

        asteroid(x,y)
        asteroid(ax,ay)
        asteroid(bx,by)
        asteroid(cx,cy)
        asteroid(dx,dy)
        if x == 2500:
           x = display_width
           y = random.randrange(60,display_height - 60)
       x += -2.5
       if ax == 2500:
          ax = display_width
          ay = random.randrange(60,display_height - 60)
       ax += -2.5
       if bx == 2500:
          bx = display_width
          by = random.randrange(60,display_height - 60)
       bx += -2.5
       if cx == 2500:
          cx = display_width
          cy = random.randrange(60,display_height - 60)
       cx += -2.5
       if dx == 2500:
          dx = display_width
           dy = random.randrange(60,display_height - 60)
       dx += -2.5

       pygame.display.update()
       clock.tick(120) #FPS
game()
```

I am trying to make this pygame code more efficient using sprites can someone show me how to do this so i can spawn more asteroids I will eventually need quite a few asteroids at once and this wont quite work well for it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're going to want to use classes to make your code more compact. Essentially, a class is a collection of variables and functions that may be used to define an object, such as an asteroid. Here is an example of a very simple asteroid class:

```
class Asteroid(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        # insert movement code here
```

Now, mutliple instances of the asteroid class may be created. This would be done like so:

```
ast1 = Asteroid(given_x,given_y,AstImg)
ast2 = Asteroid(given_x,given_y,AstImg)
ast3 = Asteroid(given_x,given_y,AstImg)
ast4 = Asteroid(given_x,given_y,AstImg)
ast5 = Asteroid(given_x,given_y,AstImg)
```

Even better would be to make a `for` loop which would create however many asteroids you'd like and even randomize starting x and y values:

```
spriteList = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(12):
    ast = Asteroid(random.randrange(1,1440),random.randrange(1,900),AstImg)
    ast.add(spriteList) # then in your while loop write spriteList.draw(gameDisplay)
                        # and spriteList.update()
```

I recommend looking further into Pygame sprite classes and how they work. [Here](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites) is a link a that may help.